# how to shift 3D matrix efficiently in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have a 3D matrix M[i*strideyz+j*stridez+k] residing on GPU, and I want to shift this matrix layer by layer: i+1-->i, and append new data to the last layer. I have written a kernel to do that, but it is very slow. I know there are some discussions here, but somehow I have not found my answer.

Here is my implementation:

```
__global void shift(int nlayers, float* M, float* inp,
                    size_t strideyz,size_t stridez)
{
  int k=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  int j=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
  for(i=0;i<nlayers-1;i++)
    M[i*strideyz+j*stridez+k]=M[(i+1)*strideyz+j*stridez+k];
  M[(Nlayers-1)*strideyz+j*stridez+k]=inp[j*stridez+k];
}
```

Comment: How did you implement that? You could show some code. It should be as fast as simply copy the cube once.

Comment: It seems to me you would want to modify a pointer, rather than physically move data.

Comment: Here is my implementation

Comment: __global void shift(int nlayers, float* M, float* inp, size_t strideyz,size_t stridez)
{
   int k=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   int  j=blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
   for(i=0;i<nlayers-1;i++)
      M[i*strideyz+j*stridez+k]=M[(i+1)*strideyz+j*stridez+k];
 
  M[(Nlayers-1)*strideyz+j*stridez+k]=inp[j*stridez+k];
}

Comment: I did use pointer rather move the data physically. But in this case, the data I need to do the finite difference in i-direction is scattered in the global memory, which dramatically hurts the performance.

Comment: I also think of using pointer arrays to present each layer in jk-plane, so that I can shift or swap the pointers. But it does not improve the performance at all because in this case, I have to read two global memory: one to find the pointer, another one the data pointed by the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems that you need to shift the "field" matrix `M` to calculate **finite differences**. From your post, I think you are going in the wrong direction.

You are defining, and presumably running, a kernel function just to perform the shift and changing the value of `M` but you should not change it; you should better define a kernel calculating the finite difference *and* performing the shift on-the-fly, by updating `M` to the new values (dictated by the finite difference scheme).

Have a look at the paper

[V. Demir and A.Z. Elsherbeni, "Compute Unified Device Architecture (CUDA) Based Finite-Difference Time-Domain (FDTD) Implementation", Applied Computational Electromagnetics Journal, vol. 25, n. 4, pp. 303-314, Apr. 2010.](http://www.engineering.olemiss.edu/~atef/pdfs/journal_papers/2010/CUDA_Based_FDTD_Implementation.pdf)

It thoroughly discusses the calculation of 3D finite differences and, although referring to electromagnetics, you can benefit from the reading for other fields (e.g., acoustics). As just a note of caution, take into account that the discussion refers to old GPU architectures, so that some solutions like the importance of using shared memory might be revised for newer (e.g., Fermi/Kepler) cards.

Finally, you can find some useful material at

[Finite Difference Time Domain Method](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/category/simulation)

Although referring to the 2D case, you may find some useful tricks.

Comment: I just want to shift the matrix the way I described. The purpose of this shift is not to update M itself, rather, I need load new element to do the finite difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use global memory. If you use shared or register memory, the operation should be much faster.

Comment: I just posted my code. Yes, I used the global memory. I did think of using shared or register memory, but the threads in the block do not use data from other threads. So I can't think of shared memory helpful here.

Comment: Derek mentioned that he ended up writing a kernel to do the swaps, Twhich was indeed faster than the Device to Device memcpy operations. Can Derek post your solution here? It may help to answer my question here.